# Hash Table Issues, reading and adding from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

Ok, Ive been having a problem. In my current project Im adding a word to my "hashtable", ( array of linked lists) and I'm adding a word in, then checking said work to see if it was added. I can tell from System outs that it was added in, but the checking/ reading part is failing then. Any help would be awsome.

testing code

```
public void testAdd(){
    assertEquals(false, commonWords.checkWord("applicable"));
    commonWords.add("applicable");
    assertEquals(true, commonWords.checkWord("applicable"));
    //restore commonWords back to original
    commonWords.create(commonFile);
}
```

adding code

```
public int add(HashableWordInterface s) {
    System.out.println("added"+s.hashCode()%TABLE_SIZE+" "+s.getString());
    table[s.hashCode()%TABLE_SIZE].put(s.getString());
    size++;
    return size;
}

public void put(String key) {
    for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next) {
        if (key.equals(curr.word)) {
            System.out.println("oops");         
            return;                     //search hit: return
        }
    }
    first = new Node(key, first); //search miss: add new node
}


public void add(String word) {
    HashableWord t= new HashableWord(word.toLowerCase().trim());
    derp.add(t);
}
```

the reading / checking code

```
public boolean  checkWord(String input) {
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    HashableWord t= new HashableWord(input);
    return derp.contains(t);
}

public boolean contains(HashableWordInterface s) {
    String input= s.getString();
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(table[(s.hashCode()%TABLE_SIZE)].get(input));
    return table[(s.hashCode()%TABLE_SIZE)].get(input);
}

public boolean get(String in) {         //return key true if key exists
    Node next = first;
    while (next != null) {
        if (next.word.equals(in)) {
            return true;
        }
        next = next.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the hash code itself

```
public int hashCode(String word){
    final int HASH_MULTIPLIER = 31; 
    int h = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        h = HASH_MULTIPLIER * h + word.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(h%(1300/3)+" "+word);
    return h;
}
```

note the methods aren't all in the same class, but at least in a subclass
edit: I forgot some of the code

```
 HashTable derp;
public Dictionary() {

    derp= new HashTable();  
}

public class HashTable implements HashTableInterface {
 private final static int TABLE_SIZE = 1300/3;
 Bucket[] table;
 private int size ;
public HashTable() {
     table = new Bucket[TABLE_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
            table[i] = new Bucket();
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. What is derp? What is table? And more important, why don't you use a `HashMap` instead of reiniventing it?